# Leave one out for multiple arguments with mapply()?

Tags: r

With a single vector `A = c(1,2,3,4,5)`, I can write

```
 sapply(A, function(a) mean(A[-a]))
```

to compute five means: the mean of A without the first element, the mean of A without the second element, etc.

I would like to do leave-one-out operations like this with two or more vectors at the same time. For example, with `B <- c(6,7,8,9,10)`, I thought I could type

```
myFunc <- function(a, b){return( c(mean(A[-a]), mean(B[-b])) )}
mapply(myFunc, A, B)
```

but that only computes the leave-one-out means of A:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  3.5 3.25    3 2.75  2.5
[2,]  8.0 8.00    8 8.00  8.0
```

and outputs a row of 8.0s for B. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the indexes you used. In the first case, it is the sequence, second it starts from 6

Comment: You mix index and value, in A index equal value so it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first vector 'A', the values are the same as the sequence.  So, when we index with that value and remove, it remove the corresponding value.  In the second vector 'B', it is not the case i.e. `B[-6]` or `B[-7]` still gives the whole vector.  Instead, loop through the sequence

```
mapply(myFunc, seq_along(A), seq_along(B))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
mapply(function(k) c(mean(A[-k]), mean(B[-k])), 1:length(A))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of looping over vector *elements* when calculating your mean, you can vectorize your code: `(sum(x) - x) / (length(x) - 1)`. Furthermore, because you have "two *or more* vectors", you better store them in a list. You can then loop over vectors with `lapply`.

`lapply` returns a list. However, if the vectors are of different length, you need to use `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` in `mapply` to return a list anyway.

```
l <- list(A, B)
f <- function(x) (sum(x) - x) / (length(x) - 1)
lapply(l, f)
# [[1]]
# [1] 3.50 3.25 3.00 2.75 2.50
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 8.50 8.25 8.00 7.75 7.50
```